# State of the deleted Component override the next Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, use-state

I have parent component, name ShoppingCartDetail. It will render many child component, name ShoppingCartProduct, each child component shows quantity of product, it has buttons to change quantity, and a button to remove current product from array of products that is added to shopping cart (like shopping cart on shopping websites).

My problem is: if change quantity of a product the press remove. The state of the removed component will override state of the next component. If I don't  increase/ decrease, no problem happen.

I have already add key attribute to child component but it not help. I would very grateful if you can give any advice.

**1. ShoppingCartDetail.js (parent):**

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faReplyAll, faLock} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import ShoppingCartProduct from './ShoppingCartProduct';

const ShoppingCartDetail = (props) => {
    const {Cart, Products, Currency} = props.Data;
    // format thounds seperator
    function formatNumber(num) {
        return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
    }
    /* Remove duplicate product in Cart arr based on ID*/
        const currentCart = [...Cart];
        // get ID list of current Cart
        let currentIdList = [];
        currentCart.forEach((product) => {
            currentIdList.push(product.id);
        })
        // removed duplicated ID
        let removedDuplicateIdList = [];
        currentIdList.forEach((id) => {
            if (!removedDuplicateIdList.includes(id)){
                removedDuplicateIdList.push(id)
            }
        })
        // create product array base on ID list, use this array to render shopping cart
        let splicedProductsList = [];
        removedDuplicateIdList.forEach((id) => {
            Products.forEach((product)=>{
                if (product.id === id){
                    splicedProductsList.push(product)
                }
            })
        })
    /* End remove duplicate product in Cart arr based on ID*/
    // Calculate total amount of Shopping Cart (re-use currentIdList)*/
    var totalAmount = 0;
    currentIdList.forEach((id) => {
        Products.forEach((product)=>{
            if (product.id === id){
                totalAmount += product.price // (default is USD)
            }
        })
    })
    // fortmat money (currency and operator and decimal)
    const showMoneyTotal = (currency, amount) => {
        switch (currency) {
            case "USD":
                return "$ " + formatNumber((amount).toFixed(2))

            case "EUR":
                return "€ " + formatNumber((amount * 0.84).toFixed(2))

            case "GBP":
                return "£ " + formatNumber((amount * 0.76).toFixed(2))

            default:
                return "$ " + formatNumber((amount).toFixed(2))
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <section className="shopping-cart-detail">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row title">
                    <div className="col">
                        <h4>Your Shopping Cart</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-auto">
                        <NavLink
                            to = "/all-collection"
                            exact = {true}
                        >
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon = {faReplyAll} className="icon"/>
                            Continue Shopping
                        </NavLink>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row shopping-cart-content">
                    <div className="col-6 order">
                        <div className="content">
                            <div className="title">Order Summary</div>
                            <div className="info">
                                <div className="container">
                                    {
                                        splicedProductsList.map((product, index) => {
                                            return (
                                                <ShoppingCartProduct Product = {product} key = {product}></ShoppingCartProduct>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3 total-amount">
                        <div className="content">
                            <div className="title">Your Cart Total</div>
                            <div className="info">
                                <div className="money">
                                    <span> {showMoneyTotal(Currency.currency, totalAmount)} </span>
                                </div>
                                <div className="check-out">
                                    <div className="wrap">
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon = {faLock} className = "icon"/>
                                        <NavLink
                                            to="/"
                                            exact={true}
                                        >
                                            Proceed To Checkout
                                        </NavLink>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="payment-card">
                                    <img
                                        alt="payment-card"
                                        src={require("../../Assets/images/section-shopping-cart-detail/payment.webp")}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        Data: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ShoppingCartDetail)
```

**2.ShoppingCartProduct.js (child)**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faPen, faTimesCircle } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import urlSlug from "url-slug";

const ShoppingCartProduct = (props) => {
    const {Cart, Currency} = props.Data;
    const {Product, dispatch} = props;
    // count quantity of a product in Shopping Cart
    const countProduct = (id) => {
        let count = 0;
        Cart.forEach((product) => {
            if (product.id === id) {
                count += 1;
            }
        })
        return count;
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        update_quantity: countProduct(Product.id),
        name: Product.name
    })
    // increase quantity when click plus button
    const increaseAddedAmount = () => {
        setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                update_quantity: prevState.update_quantity + 1
            }
        })
    }
    // decrease quantity when click substract button
    const decreaseAddedAmount = () => {
        if (state.update_quantity > 0) {
            setState((prevState) => {
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    update_quantity: prevState.update_quantity - 1
                }
            })
        }
    } 
    return (
        <div className={`row product-row ${Product.name}`} key = {Product}>
            <div className="col-2 img">
                <img 
                    alt="product"
                    src = {Product.main__image}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="col-10 product-detail">
                <div className="row name">
                    <div className="col">
                        <NavLink
                            to = {`/product/${urlSlug(Product.name)}`}
                            exact = {true}
                        >
                            {Product.name}
                        </NavLink>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row price">
                    <div className="col">{showMoney(Currency.currency, 1, Product)}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="row quantity-title">
                    <div className="col">
                        Quantity
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row quantity-row">
                    <div className="col-3 quantity">
                        <div className="wrap">
                            
                            <span 
                                className="decrease"
                                onClick = {()=>{decreaseAddedAmount()}}
                            >-</span>
                            <span className='count'>
                                {state.update_quantity}
                            </span>
                            <span 
                                className="increase"
                                onClick = {()=>{increaseAddedAmount()}}
                            >+</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3 update-quantity">
                        <div 
                            className="wrap" 
                            onClick = {()=>dispatch({type: "UPDATE", id: Product.id, quantity: state.update_quantity})}
                        >
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon = {faPen} className="icon"/>
                            Update
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-3 remove-product">
                        <div 
                            className="wrap"
                            onClick = {()=>{dispatch({type: "REMOVE", id: Product.id})}}
                        >
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon = {faTimesCircle} className="icon"/>
                            Remove
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        Data: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ShoppingCartProduct)
```

Comment: I think your mapping is based on index-based, so whenever your top index will remove, it will override next component, change that to id based and your problem will fixed

Comment: Thank you Nisharg Shah, but could you please explain a bit more about "change that to id based", I am sorry because I am newer.

Comment: like if you are following an index-based approach, one thing will remove, it will automatically shift to another component, and id based approach means something like that { 1: {<all objects/array>}, 2: {}, 3: {} }, so it will only focus the current id of that state and that problem will be fixed

Comment: thank you so much I will try it

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity try to pass the clicked product as a prop and then use javascript method called findIndex() to find the id of the clicked product inside the Cart array and store it in a variable. After getting the id then use splice to generate a new array of cart without that id that you found. You can use this snippet of code for reference.

```
const index = this.state.cart.findIndex(
        (cartItem) => cartItem.id === clickedProduct.id
      );
      let newCart = [...this.state.cart];
      if (index >= 0) {
        newCart.splice(index, 1);
      }
```